# Алиас запуска Webstorm в консоли с дальнейшым открытием проекта, как исправить?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, webstorm

По примеру в статьи: [Автоматизация старта верстки](http://glivera-team.github.io/how-to/2016/05/18/bash-start.html)
 я написал свой алгоритм под Linux (Ubuntu), все запускается, создается, клонируется, устанавливаются зависимости и даже открывается редактор, но почему то не хочет открыть проект в браузере, как допустим у автора примера. Я пробовал по-разному делать этот алгоритм, и пришел к выводу что неверно задаю алиас для запуска Webstorm. У автора это делалось по Windows, а вот под Linux понятное дело так не запустишь редактор с консоли. Я написал следующее в .bashrc:

```js
alias pro = 'cd /home/******/Dropbox/Projects/Work2017/'
alias storm = 'bash $HOME/WebStorm-162.1812.21/bin/webstorm.sh' $*

  createNewProject() {#
    Переходим в папку с проектами
    pro# Клонируем стартовый шаблон с гитхаба
    git clone репозиторий
    # Переименовываем название шаблона на папку '$1'
    mv / home /*****/ Dropbox / Projects / Work2017 / gulp - dev / home /*****/ Dropbox / Projects / Work2017 / $1
    # Переходим в папку $1
    cd $1
    # Удаляем ненужные папки и папку с гитом
    rm - rf.git settings.jar
    # Линкуем глобальные пакеты(сюда можно поставить npm install)
    yarn install
    bower install 
    # Открываем проект в WebStorm
    storm / home /******/ Dropbox / Projects / Work2017 / $1# Запускаем gulp(или npm run start)
    gulp
  }
alias new = createNewProject
```

так вот меня смущает правильность записи алиаса запуска Webstorm, подскажите что я сделал неверно и как правильно?

```
alias storm='bash $HOME/WebStorm-162.1812.21/bin/webstorm.sh' $*
```

Comment: Одинарные кавычки, где не интерполируется `$HOME`? Пробелы вокруг `=`?

Comment: не совсем понял про  где не интерполируется $HOME?

Comment: Последняя строка в Вашем тексте. Там одинарные кавычки